# How to find maximum concurrent processes Passenger can create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I'm running passenger with REE on a Rackspace cloud server. Is there any way to find out what is the maximum concurrent processes Passenger can create/handle with the provided infrastructure/hardware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a better and easier option. 
I'm monitoring both my Application and EC2 instance (it should also run on Rackspace) with [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com/). All I need to do now is find a load testing tool & put the load on my instance. NewRelic shows how many instances Passenger is creating & what is the resource consumption (RAM, CPU..etc) for the same.

Answer (score 4):

By default the maximum number of Passenger instances spawned is six. You can adjust this in the configuration. Phusion provide excellent guidelines for setting this value in their documentation:

Nginx - http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerMaxPoolSize

Apache - http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_passengermaxpoolsize_lt_integer_gt

Comment: Thanks for the links, it explains it quite well. But, still there is no straight forward way of finding this out! Is there any tool to load Passenger & check what's the max it can go with provided infrastructure?

Comment: Not automated, no. You could load test your app with varying values for MaxInstances, at a certain point you will see a levelling off or even reduction in RPS when you have too many.